# What does this C++ code mean

Tags: c++, webkit

I was trying to understand how webkit parses urls, and I'm having a hard time making heads or tails of this:

```
Vector<char, 4096> buffer(fragmentEnd * 3 + 1);
```

This line is on line 1214 (you can see it here: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/platform/KURL.cpp#L1214).  I get that it's making a vector of type char, with each entry being an array of char 4096 bytes large, but I don't get the `buffer(fragmentEnd * 3 + 1)` part.

I think that it confuses me most b/c I can't find where the buffer variable is instantiated anywhere (shouldn't it be something more like `Vector<char, 4096> buffer = new Vector<char, 4096>(...)`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is a pretty unbelievably bad chunk of C++ code.

Comment: Hey, those `matchLetter()` lines are `'g','r','e','a','t'` ;)

Comment: @Neil, line 50, `using namespace WTF;` says it all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `buffer` variable is constructed exactly on that line:

```
Vector<char, 4096> buffer(fragmentEnd * 3 + 1);
```

Walking through the steps that the compiler takes, it first ensures that there are `sizeof(Vector<char, 4096>)` bytes of space on the stack into which it can construct the `Vector<char, 4096> buffer` object. It then calls a `Vector<char, 4096>` constructor that can take an `int` (because `fragmentEnd * 3 + 1` is an `int`) on the storage in the stack.

In the current `Vector` sources, there is no constructor that takes an `int`. However, there is [a constructor that takes a `size_t`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/JavaScriptCore/wtf/Vector.h?rev=59463#L506) (an unsigned `int`), so the compiler will statically cast the result `fragmentEnd * 3 + 1` to a `size_t` and invoke that constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> I get that it's making a vector of type char, with each entry being an array of char 4096 bytes large

It's not. The WTF::Vector template takes two template parameters. The first is the element type (in this case char, which means that each element is a char, not an array of chars). The second is the inline capacity, i.e. the number of bytes the vector can store without allocating additional memory on the heap.

> but I don't get the buffer(fragmentEnd * 3 + 1) part.

The syntax to create a variable on the stack is `type variablename(constructor,arguments);`. So `buffer` is the name of the variable and `fragmentEnd * 3 + 1` is the argument to `Vector<char, 4096>`'s constructor (which specifies the vector's initial size).

Answer (score 1):

No it shouldn't, `new` may or may not be used to allocate a new object in C++, unlike, for example, C#.

Explanation:

`Vector` is not a standard class, like STL's vector.

The line creates object buffer, on stack, of type Vector. It then passes parameters to the constructor (what's in the brackets)

Answer (score 1):

Check out more info about the Vector class that is used (it is the Vector from webkit (WTF namespace) - not from std).

Check the Vector.h header file. It is [here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/JavaScriptCore/wtf/Vector.h?rev=59463#L506).

Comment: To complete: Initialization occurs in the lines below. it takes a reference to the internal buffer held in the Vector class and populates it (I'm referring to the part of the code you showed us).

Answer (score 1):

From Iulian's link, the source for aptly-named `WTF::Vector` says that the second template parameter is named `inlineCapacity`.

So, it has something to do with some kind of optimization which should have nothing to do with functionality. Ignore it. The size of the buffer is `fragmentEnd * 3 + 1`, nothing more or less.